# Is it possible to block users from using your app on firebase?

Tags: dart

As an example, let's say i have create an e-commerce app which allows people to open a shop on the app. every shop is supposed to pay rent at the end of the month. if the don't I want want to prevent them from using the shop and hide the app from being viewed by other users who want to buy from the shop. So is it possible to block such a user until they pay rent?

Comment: This appears to be a generic design question, which is outside of the scope of this forum. I would not be surprised if this question goes unanswered, downvoted, and closed under the "Needs more focus" criteria: https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions , please see the guide on how to ask questions on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.